# Objective-C Thread 1: signal SIGABRT no bad connections

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is my code.

```
NSURL *quoteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qwoatzz.com/quoates.json"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:quoteURL];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
// NSLog(@"dataDictionary : %@", dataDictionary);

NSDictionary *posts = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"picture1"];

self.quoteArray = [posts objectForKey:@"quote"];
self.personArray = [posts objectForKey:@"person"];

int r = arc4random_uniform(quoteArray.count);

mainText.text = [quoteArray objectAtIndex:r];
subText.text = [personArray objectAtIndex:r];
```

I am getting the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error on the line starting with "`self.quoteArray`". I have no broken connection in the storyboard on any View Controllers. I am also getting "`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`" in the console. What is the problem?

Code that was working:

```
SURL *quoteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qwoatzz.com/quoates.json"];


NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:quoteURL];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
// NSLog(@"dataDictionary : %@", dataDictionary);

NSArray *posts = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"picture3"];

int i = 0;

NSString *quote = [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"quote"];
NSString *person = [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"person"];

i++;

NSString *quote1 = [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"quote"];
NSString *person1 = [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"person"];

i++;

NSString *quote2 = [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"quote"];
NSString *person2 = [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"person"];

NSArray *quotesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:quote, quote1, quote2, nil];
NSArray *personArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:person, person1, person2, nil];

int r = arc4random_uniform(quotesArray.count);

mainText.text = [quotesArray objectAtIndex:r];
subText.text = [personArray objectAtIndex:r];
```

I'm not using that code anymore as I will have an unspecified amount of objects in the JSON file.

EDIT: It is now directing me to main.m when I get the error which shows this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

and the error is on "`return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`"

Comment: what NSLog(@"dataDictionary : %@", dataDictionary); dataDictionary prints

Comment: It just prints out the quoates.json file.

Comment: Go to the Breakpoint Navigator and set a break on Objective-C exceptions.  It should cause the crash to stop somewhere more useful that 'main'.

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient context in the code snippet, and only partial information in the error message, so not possible to be certain here. You should start by confirming that "picture1" actually is returning a dictionary and that it contains the array "quote" that you expect it does.

Comparing your two code sections, `[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"picture1"];` returns an NSArray that contains NSDictionaries in the working version for `posts` but you are treating it as just returning an NSDictionary in your new code. This appears likely to be the problem.

Posting a greater portion of the error message from the SIGABRT would immediately assist in narrowing down the type of problem.

Comment: I made the json file so I am very sure that "quote" does exist and it was working before (I'll show the text I had before that does work on the question).

Comment: You're right, go to the URL that he gets the JSON from and you can see the response is a dictionary, and each value in the dictionary is an array.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clear when you go to the URL provided and see the results below. The response is a dictionary. The object associated with the key *picture1* is an ***array of dictionaries***.

```
{
    "picture1":
    [
        {
            "quote":"A little nonsense now and then, is cherished by the wisest men.", 
            "person":"Roald Dahl"
        }, 
        {
            "quote":"It's a good idea always to do something relaxing prior to making an important decision in your life.",
            "person":"Paulo Coelho"
        },
        {
            "quote":"Work. Don't Think. Relax.",
            "person":"Ray Bradbury"
        }   
    ]
}
```

You need to get the object for key (you can use the shortcut `yourDict[@"theKey"]` instead of `objectForKey`) for picture1 - that is an array. Then each object in that array is a dictionary, so if you want to get all of the quotes/persons, this is what you'd do:

```
NSArray *picture1Posts = dataDictionary[@"person1"];
NSMutableArray *quotes = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *persons = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dict in picture1Posts) {
   [quotes addObject:dict[@"quote"];
   [persons addObject:dict[@"person"];
}
```

Be aware that inserting nil into an array will crash it, so you'll want to make sure that `dict[@"quote"]` and `dict[@"person"]` isn't nil before adding, this was just to show you your problem.